# Prove that $|ab+1|>|a+b|$ with $|a|<1$, $|b|<1$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, absolute-value

Prove that $|ab+1|>|a+b|$ with $|a|<1$, $|b|<1$

$a$, $b$ are real numbers

Where $|a|$ is the absolute value of $a$.

Every time, I arrive to a dead-end.

Comment: I don't think the statement is even true.  If you take $b = \tfrac 1a$, then $\left|ab+1\right| = 2$, while $\left|a + b\right| = \left| a + \tfrac 1a\right| \geq 2$.

Comment: @Maciek My mistake |a|<1

Comment: Ok.  I'd note that $ab+1 > 0$, so the left absolute values can be dropped.  If $a+b < 0$, you can consider the equation in $-a$ and $-b$: the left hand side doesn't change, so you can drop the absolutes on the right side as well.  Then you're left with showing $ab + 1 > a + b$.  Does that help?

Comment: That's what i did but it felt not enough

Comment: $\lvert 1+ab\rvert^2 - \lvert a+b\rvert^2 > 0$ is a nice computation.

Comment: The inequality holds as long as both $|a|, |b|$ are either $<1$ or both $>1$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$(ab+1)^2-(a+b)^2=(ab-a-b+1)(ab+a+b+1)=(a-1)(b-1)(a+1)(b+1)=(a^2-1)(b^2-1)>0$$

Comment: +1 but this is no "hint." :)

Comment: Err... Got me there.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $a<1$ and $b<1$, we have
$$(a-1)(b-1)>0.$$
Similarly
$$(a+1)(b+1)>0.$$
Expanding both of them gives you the answer.