# How to prove this absolute value implication?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Prove:

$$(|x| < 1)\wedge(|y| < 1) \Rightarrow \frac{|x-y|}{|1 - xy|} < 1$$

for all real $x$ and $y$.

I've tried approaching it via proof by contradiction:

$(\exists x,y\in\mathbb{R})(|x| < 1 \wedge|y| < 1)\wedge\left(\dfrac{|x-y|}{|1-xy|} < 1\right)$

But I can't seem to get anywhere useful. I run into the same issues with contrapositive.

Many thanks!

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times, you can search for it [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7Cx-y%7C%20%3C%20%7C1-xy%7C%24)

Comment: For real numbers: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1535052/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2568386/42969

Comment: For complex numbers: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/198582/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/506058/42969

Comment: Could I convert |x-y| < |1-xy| to |x+y|<1+|xy|? Or somehow get to addition from subtraction?

Comment: Just set $x = a$ and $y = -b$.

Comment: Well doesn't that make things easier

Comment: I think it does: $\frac{|x-y|}{|1-xy|} = \frac{|a+b|}{|1+ab|}$

Comment: Yeah and it works directly or by contradiction ( unnecessary in hindsight ) , (x-y)^2-(1-xy)^2 >=1 yields 0>=1.